# How to solve TapJacking vulnerability in ReactNative app

Tags: android, security, react-native, clickjacking

I know I can apply these property filterTouchesWhenObscured method onFilterTouchEventForSecurity in my view but I want to apply on my every clickable view so how can I apply it..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the need to fix a Tapjacking scenario today.
What works for my app is this:

Eject the app from RN and add this to the MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // get the root view and activate touch filtering to prevent tap jacking
    View v = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    v.setFilterTouchesWhenObscured(true);
}
```

Comment: Are you still using this and how did it work out?

Comment: Sorry the project where I had to solve this issue is not in production anymore, so I don't know if the solution still works.