# How to Avoid TapJacking in react-native

Tags: android, react-native

There is a TapJacking issue in the android app (React-Native). I have tried available solutions on StackOverflow but didn't work.

I have updated minsdkversion :24

Solution i tried  in Splash.java and did't work:

```
 View v = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    v.setFilterTouchesWhenObscured(true);
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51818363/how-to-solve-tapjacking-vulnerability-in-reactnative-app

Comment: @allnewryan i have tried same but answer didn't resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing around with removing and adding views lately.
Would it be possible to put the button in a parent linear layout that shares the same properties as the button, then onClick `removeView(button)`? Because the parent view is identical to your button user shouldn't notice anything, once tapJacking timeout is complete add the button back.

Comment: @Debug_logger did my answer help?